# Extension degree of the minimal splitting field of $X^4+2tX^2+t$ over $\mathbb{C}(t)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

I want to find the extension degree of  the minimal splitting field $L$ of $X^4+2tX^2+t$ over $\mathbb{C}(t)$.

What I know are followings.

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(X) := X^4+2tX^2+t$ and $K = \mathbb{C}(t)$.
Since $f$ is irreducible over $K$, $[K(\alpha):K] = 4$.
If $K(\alpha) = L$, then $\beta$, a root of $f$ which is not $\pm \alpha$ (this exists as the character of $K$ is zero and $f$ is separable) is contained in $K(\alpha)$.
Also, since the roots of $X^2+2tX+t$ is $\alpha^2, \beta^2$, we have $\alpha^2\beta^2=t$, and $\alpha\beta=\pm \sqrt{t} \in K(\alpha)$.
Therefore, we have $L = K(\alpha, \beta) = K(\alpha, \sqrt{t})$ or $L=K(\alpha)$.
This implies $[L:K] = 8$ or $[L:K]=4$.

I think $[L:K] = 8$, but cannot show $\sqrt{t} \notin K(\alpha)$.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it might help to think of $\alpha$ as $\pm \sqrt{-t \pm \sqrt{t^2 - t}}$?  Therefore, an intermediate quadratic extension of $K$ would be $\mathbb{C}(t, \sqrt{t^2 - t})$; maybe you can prove that there's a unique intermediate quadratic extension, so it suffices to show $\sqrt{t} \notin \mathbb{C}(t, \sqrt{t^2 - t})$?

Comment: @DanielSchepler I don't show there is a unique intermediate quadratic extension now, but I think $\sqrt{t} \in K(\alpha)$ if and only if $[L:K]=4$.
If $\sqrt{t} \in K(\alpha)$, then $[L:K] = [K(\alpha): K] = 4$, and conversely if $\sqrt{t} \notin K(\alpha)$, then $[L:K] = [K(\alpha, \sqrt{t}):K(\alpha)][K(\alpha):K] = 8$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $(\alpha^2 + t)^2 = t^2 - t$; and similarly, as you observed, $(\alpha \beta)^2 = t$.  Therefore, if we set $u := \frac{\alpha^2 + t}{\alpha\beta} \in L$, then $u^2 = t-1$.

Now, the original polynomial $X^4 + 2t X^2 + t = X^4 + 2(u^2+1) X^2 + (u^2+1)$ is still irreducible over $\mathbb{C}[u]$, applying Eisenstein's criterion with the prime ideal $\langle u + i \rangle$.  Therefore, by Gauss' lemma, $X^4 + 2t X^2 + t$ is also irreducible over $\mathbb{C}(u)$.  It follows that $[L : \mathbb{C}(t)] \ge [\mathbb{C}(u, \alpha) : \mathbb{C}(u)] [\mathbb{C}(u) : \mathbb{C}(t)] = 4 \cdot 2 = 8$.  Since you have also already shown that $[L : K] \le 8$, it follows that $[L : K] = 8$.